# Is deallocation of multiple large bunches of memory worth it?

Tags: memory, memory-management

Say for instance I write a program which allocates a bunch of large objects when it is initialized. Then the program runs for awhile, perhaps indefinitely, and when it's time to terminate, each of the large initialized objects are freed.

So my question is, will it take longer to manually deallocate each block of memory separately at the end of the program's life or would it be better to let the system unload the program and deallocate all of the virtual memory given to the program by the system at the same time.

Would it be safe and/or faster? Also, if it is safe, does the compiler do this when set to optimise anyway?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what language you're using.  C++?

Comment: Well it's more of a general question for any language where you can manage memory yourself. But yeah, C or C++ are the main languages I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Not all systems will free a memory for you when application terminates. Of course most of the modern desktop systems will do this, so if you are going to run your program only on Linux or Mac(or Windows), you can leave the deallocation to the system.

2) Often it is needed to make some operations with the data on termination, not just to free the memory. So if you are going to develop such program design that makes it hard to deallocate objects at the end manually, then it can happen that later you will need to perform some code before exiting and you will face up with hard problem.

2') Sometimes even if you think that your program will need some objects all the way until dead, later you may want to make a library from you program or change a project to load and unload you big objects and the poor design of your program will make this hard or impossible.

3) Moreover, the program deallocation performance depends on the implementation of the allocator you are going to use in your program. The system deallocation depends on the system memory management and even for a single system there can be several implementations. So if you face with allocation/deallocation performance problems - you would like to develop better allocator rather then hope on the system.

4) So my opinion is: When you deallocate memory manually at the end -  you are always on a right way. When you don't do this, perhaps you can get some ambiguous benefits in several cases, but likely you will just face with the problems sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Well most OS will free the memory at exit if the program, but the bigger question is why would you want it to have to?

Is it faster?  Hard to say with memory sometimes. I would guess not really and definitely not worth breaking good coding practices anyway.

Is it safe?  Define safe... Will your OS crash? Probably not. Will your code be susceptible to memory leaks or other problems?  Absolutely,  it will. In fact you are basically telling it you want memory leaks.

Best practice is to always free your memory when you are done with it.  With C and C++, every malloced or new block of memory should have a corresponding free or delete.

It is a bad idea to rely on the OS to free your memory because it not only makes your code look bad and makes it less portable,  but if the program was ever integrated into another program,  then you will likely be tracking down memory leaks for hours.

So, short answer,  always do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Programs with a short maintenance life time are good candidates for memory deallocation by "exit() and let the kernel sort them out." However, if the program will last more than a few months you have to consider the maintenance burden.

For instance, consider that someone may realize that a subsequent stage is required in the program, and some of the data is not needed, or not needed in memory. They now have to go and find out how to deallocate the memory, properly removing stale references, etc.